# Динамическая высота двух и более фреймов на странице

Tags: javascript, iframe, события

У меня на странице размещен фрейм, размер которого может динамически меняться, поэтому каждые 100мс во фрейме выполняется postMessage для передачи его высоты родителю (основному окну).

Но если на страницу добавить еще один фрейм, то postMessage каждого из них будет менять размер сразу обоих фреймов.

Ниже представлен мой код:

**Главная страница**

```
<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myEventMethod = 
                window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
            var myEventListener = window[myEventMethod];
            var myEventMessage = 
                myEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
            myEventListener(myEventMessage, function (e) {
                if (e.data === parseInt(e.data)) 
                    document.getElementById('my-iframe-id').height = e.data + "px";
            }, false);
        </script>
        <iframe id="my-iframe-id" src='./widget-example.html' frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <script type="text/javascript">     
    var m = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";     
    window[m](m == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message", function (e) {
    if (e.data === parseInt(e.data))document.getElementById('widget-id-2').height = e.data + "px";
    }, false);
    </script>
    <iframe src='./widget-example2.html' id='widget-id-2' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%'> </iframe>
```

**Содержимое фреймов**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postm() {
    window.parent.postMessage(
      document.body.scrollHeight, "*"
    )
  }
  setInterval(postm, 100);
</script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы высота каждого фрейма передавалась индивидуально? Реализовать надо без использования jQuery.

Желательно, если можно, приложите рабочий код.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: Разве нельзя заменить `document.body.scrollHeight` на что-то вроде `{ sender: 'frame1', height: document.body.scrollHeight }` ?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что вы слушаете один и тот же объект `window`, получаете одно и тоже событие от двух разных фреймов и эти события вы никак не различаете.

1. Нужно научиться различать фреймы.
   Для этого можно использовать какой нибудь атрибут например `<body id="frame-1">` и соответственно `<body id="frame-2">`.
2. Далее код для фреймов должен выглядеть как-то так

```js
function postm() {
  window.parent.postMessage(
    document.body.id + ':' + document.body.scrollHeight,
    "*"
  )
}
setInterval(postm, 100);
```

Ну и принимая сообщения в родительском окне, их (события) уже нужно различать:

```js
myEventListener(myEventMessage, function (e) {
  if (e.data === parseInt(e.data)) {
    var parts = e.data.split(':');
    document.getElementById(parts[0]).height = parts[1] + "px";
  }, false);
```

Ну и при таком подходе, достаточно только одного обработчика события `onmessage` в главном окне